# get_the_ID() gives notice in 404 page

Tags: 404-error, notices

I'm using get_the_ID() in my wp_enqueue_scripts action due to some needs, But as result I'm getting the following notice (wp-debug is on):

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp\www\WordPress\wp-includes\post-template.php on line 29

I know why this happens, My question is why should this happen? Isn't WordPress supposed to know that there is no $post assigned to 404 and return an empty result?

Do I have to use:

```
if( !is_object($post) ) return;
```

Everywhere I use get_the_ID() in order to get rid of that Notice?

Comment: This question is out-of-date for WordPress 4.0 and later. `get_the_ID()` can now be safely called anywhere its defined without raising a warning, even if there is no global `$post` set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`get_the_ID()` is broken.

```
function get_the_ID() {
    return get_post()->ID;
}
```

It tries to use the member `ID` on a function that returns a `post` object *sometimes:*

```
/* 
 * @return WP_Post|null WP_Post on success or null on failure
 */
function get_post( $post = null, $output = OBJECT, $filter = 'raw' ) {
```

`get_posts()` can return `NULL`, and `NULL` has no member `ID`, because it is not an object.

There is no global `post` object on a 404 page. And because `$post` is a global variable, it can be removed *everywhere,* even on single pages.

So whenever you use `get_the_ID()`, you have to test for a `post` object.

```
if ( get_post() )
{
    $id = get_the_ID();
    // do something
}
```

There two lessons to learn here:

1. Never trust the WordPress API. Read the code, understand its limitations.
2. Avoid global variables in your own code. Treat each one as a *serious bug* and get rid of it immediately.

Comment: I had a bunch of warnings on 404 pages too, all related to the $post object. Is it better to create and use a function like so,  http://pastebin.com/EwEZAQzi on locations it makes sense? My main issue is that I use the post object to create localised JS vars ( using post meta ) in functions.php, which still runs on a 404 page.

Comment: @Tim Just don't run you script on 404 pages. Check for `is_singular()` before you are enqueuing the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if you're in a 404 page:

```
if( is_404() ) {
    return;
}
get_the_ID();
// ...
```

#### Reference

[`is_404()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_404)

Comment: WordPress has a whole host of [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags), in fact.